# How to convert for each in list into lambda expression c#

Tags: c#

I have the following looping foreach in list. I would like to know how I can write this in lambda expression as part of my learning.

```
int count = 0;
foreach (var c in result)
{
    response.AllChecklist[0].obj.Name = c.Name;
    response.AllChecklist[0].obj.Category = c.Category;
    response.AllChecklist[0].obj.Code = c.Code;
    response.AllChecklist[0].obj.chk[count].Name = c.Name;
    response.AllChecklist[0].obj.chk[count].Type = c.Type;
    response.AllChecklist[0].obj.chk[count].chktatusCode = c.chktatusCode;
    response.AllChecklist[0].obj.chk[count].chktatusReasonCode = c.chktatusReasonCode;
    count++;
}
```

Should I have to  write like this result.ForEach()

Answer (score 1):

I need to know the type of chk. I will assume its a class called Chk

```
response.AllCheckList[0].obj.chk = result.Select(r=>
       new Chk{
          Name = r.Name,
          Type = r.Type,
          chkStatusCode = r.chkStatusCode,
          chkStatusReason = r.chkStatusReason
      }).ToArray();
```

Comment: Ya its class. but i am getting the error Error 172 Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type

Comment: u gonna have to post the code you are trying to run with the types of everything, that message says you are using `dynamic` somewhere

Comment: its of var result. and in this context its dynamic list

Comment: `var result` isnt anything. BUt as the error says, you cant do linq and dynamic together